# How do I make a button invisible just after click?

Tags: android, button, visible, invisible

I would like to know how to make a button visible but when clicked I want it to be invisible so it won't be shown at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button button = (Button) v;
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

This makes it go invisible but still take up space in the layout, switching the last row for:

```
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

would make it "fold" and it will not only be invisible but won't take up space in the layuout either.

Comment: Thank you so much! It took me hours to find the answer. I went thru hell to find the code..!

Comment: Since you are new to the site ill tell you this. If you find an answer that solves your problem mark it as "Accepted". So others know which answer helped you. It's a green checkbox under the votes widget to the left of the answer.

Comment: sorry I thought the " Was this post useful to you?    " was the green marker. (Can u email me on wahid-connected@hotmail.com) u seem like a smart guy i need a little help.

Comment: The whole point of this site is to avoid asking/answering the same stuff all over again. If you have a question: Search here. If you cant find a similar question: ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. `setVisibility(View.Invisible)` inside `OnClickListener()` of the button

Answer (score 1):

put this line in your `Button's on click method.`

```
Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

EDIT: if you make totally gone the Button view and then try

```
Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this in your OnClickListener:

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

If you want it to be totally invisible and take up layout space use

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way.

```
yourbutton.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
```

This will be remove your button from your layout so other control will be used that space.

If you want to just hide and keep button size with another layout you can use

```
yourbutton.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
```