# Android - Pressing the correct buttons before the wrong

Tags: android, button, click

Please read this first.
[How do I make a button invisible just after click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495088/android-how-do-i-make-a-button-invisible-just-after-click)

Now I have created the visible button to vanish after clicking the button.

If i had **button 1**, **button 2**, **button 3**.

Example: I wanted the user to touch the **button 3** before **button 2** and **button 1**.
then has to touch **button 1** then **button 2**.

If user touches **button 1** first then it will take him to an activity class.

How do i make this happen?
(This is for a game I have under development)

Thank You!

Wahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage visibility and enablity of button -

```
    b1.setEnabled(true);
    b2.setEnabled(true);
    b3.setEnabled(true);
    boolean pressed=false;

    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pressed=true;
            b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);                
        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(pressed==false)
            {
                //Start New Activity Here
            }               
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pressed=true;

        }
    });
```

Comment: do you really need to invisible button?? you could have used mButton.setEnabled(false) for just disabling button. this is the code which make button disappear and manage the way you want   user to click them. this works fine here.can you show me the errors/logcat?

Comment: please check edited answer now.i changed it for your requirement for " QUOTE)you want to launch another activity when the user press button 1?(END QUOTE) yes but i didnt mean it that way. I meant like if he does press button 1 before button 2 & 3. It will take him to an activity unless if he presses button 3 first. then button 1 will just vanish "

Comment: Please email me on wahid-connected@hotmail.com  I'll send you my screenshots of errors.   http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/2438/screeh.png

Comment: I don't have access to gmail and i cannot see the image you had given link for.please paste your logcat here.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean field for the third button. When the user presses the third button, in your case, you set that boolean to true.
In the onClick method of the first button them you check that field, if it's false you call your activity.

Comment: The default value of boolean field must be set to false

Answer (score 0):

you want to launch another activity when the user press button 1?

then you should:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

To pass info, you can use extras:

```
myIntent.putExtra("key", value);
```

Comment: (QUOTE)you want to launch another activity when the user press button 1?(END QUOTE) yes but i didnt mean it that way. I meant like if he does press button 1 before button 2 & 3. It will take him to an activity unless if he presses button 3 first. then button 1 will just vanish.