# How do I remove an imageButton after it is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

```
View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

I want the imageButton to disappear or delete after the image view is clicked. I am making this app on Android Studios and when it runs and I click the imageButton the view does not become hidden.

Thank you to all who are willing to help!!!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495088/how-do-i-make-a-button-invisible-just-after-click)

Comment: setVisibility(View.Invisible) inside OnClickListener() of the button

Comment: set the onClickListner as Pablo said in his answer. You will get it working.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the onClick handler but maybe you are not setting it:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};

btn.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler3 ); // this sets the handler
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, I'm giving it a try right now. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

We can disable buttons in android. Try the below code.

```
View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
    }

};
```

Comment: It was about **removing** the `ImageButton` not **disabling** it.

Comment: then this should work.  btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: why you are posting two different answers ? edit the first answer or delete one

Answer (score -1):

Use `btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` instead of `View.Gone`

```
View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
};
```

Comment: why is it so?? does it made any difference ?? I mean the things about removing either you do GONE or INVISIBLE. both will remove.

Comment: no If you are doing GONE then It will remove view from the parent view and space of that view also remove but If you are doing INVISIBLE then the space will remain of that view and just view is INVISIBLE.